# spring boot: how to build custom parameterised test slice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

i would like to create an annotation that works like `@WebMvcTest` (which have a lot of paramters, including controllers to test) but also loads additional configuration `@Import(...)`.

i've seen the post https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4 but it describes parameterless annotation.

How can I 'extend' the existing test slice?

Comment: You can create class and extend your test from its

Answer (score 2):

Controller and additional configuration can be imported like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = {MyController.class, MyConfig.class})
```

But if you still want to extend `@WebMvcTest` annotation,
you can create a composed annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@WebMvcTest
public @interface ExtendedMvcTest {

    @AliasFor(annotation = WebMvcTest.class, attribute = "value")
    Class<?>[] includeClasses() default {};
}
```

And then apply it to a test:

```
@ExtendedMvcTest(includeClasses = {MyController.class, MyConfig.class})
class WebTests {}
```